# How to let word does not show italics?

Tags: math-mode

According to the latex code, the resulting (P_{o}) and (\mu W) will appear in italics.
How to avoid italics?

```
It results that the output power of the whole system \(P_{o}\) has 0.348 \(\mu W\)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The letter “P” should be in italics, because it represents a scalar variable. To the contrary, the subscript “o” should be in upright type because it's a textual abbreviation.

For the units, use `siunitx` that guarantees uniformity. The unit is `\micro\watt`, which can be shortened to `\uW`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

It results that the output power \(P_{\mathrm{o}}\)
of the whole system is \qty{0.348}{\micro\watt}.

It results that the output power \(P_{\mathrm{o}}\)
of the whole system is \qty{0.348}{\uW}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ‘The letter “P” should be in italics, because it represents a scalar variable.’ — It’s worth noting that this convention is a bit field-dependent, so while in most fields/contexts I’d agree it’s correct, it’s not an absolute universal rule.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Can you please make examples?